# Not able to connect to GCP mysql database using API KEY , Error : Project specified in the request is invalid

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to run my application connecting to mysql database in google cloud. But got an exception:

> The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are
>   available if running on Google App Engine, Google Compute Engine, or
>   Google Cloud Shell. Otherwise, the environment variable
>   GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file
>   defining the credentials. See
>   https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials
>   for more information.

I went to the page and downloaded the json file.Also set up an env variable to the file. Now I have below error:

> 400 Bad Request { "code" : 400, "errors" : [ { "domain" : "global",
>   "message" : "Project specified in the request is invalid.", "reason" :
>   "errorInvalidProject" } ], "message" : "Project specified in the
>   request is invalid." }

I believe the project id is correct in the json file and not sure what went wrong.

Let me know if you have any questions. Look forward to your reply.

Thanks,
Di

Expected:

My local application should be able to connect to database server in google cloud.

Actual:

get an error saying Project specified in the request is invalid.

UserProjectInvalid  The user project specified in the request is invalid, either because it is a malformed project id or because it refers to a non-existent project.

I believe the project id should be correct and it is in the json file I downloaded. I have not modified it.

Comment: Make sure you are setting correct project ID: gcloud config set project

Comment: It is awkward but it is my problem , the mysql connection string is wrong. I fixed it.Thanks